# Prove that $\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2 | |x|+|y| = 1\}$ has Jordan content 0.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing, solution-verification

Here is my working definition of what it means to have Jordan Content 0 (not that I am in a Real Analysis course, not an Algebra or Topology course).

> A bounded subset $S$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is said to have Jordan content 0 provided that for each $\epsilon>0$, there is a finite collection $\mathcal{F}$ of generalized rectangles in $\mathbb{R}^n$ that cover $S$, the sum of whose volumes is less than $\epsilon$.

The textbook gives an example for if $S = \{(x,y) | 0\leq x \leq 1, y=x \}$, where it says that for every natural nuber $k$, if we let $\{I_j\}_{1\leq j \leq k}$ be the collection of $k$ generalized rectangles defined by
$$ I_j = \left[ \frac{j-1}{k}, \frac{j}{k} \right] \times \left[ \frac{j-1}{k}, \frac{j}{k} \right],\ \ 1 \leq j \leq k$$
then this clearly covers $S$ and has volume $1/k$, which by the Archimedean property means that we can choose $k$ such that the volume is less than $\epsilon$.

I have no idea how to use this logic to solve the problem at hand without essentially solving it 4 times for 4 segments.

Comment: Honestly, solving it separately for each segment is essentially the best way to go. However, you can leverage your work for the first segment by noting that any cover of the first segment can be "rotated $90^\circ$" to produce a cover of the second segment.

Answer (score 1):

A good way that gives you a lot of such sets is to prove the following statements.

- The graph of a continuous function over a closed interval has Jordan content 0.
- The union of two Jordan content 0 sets has Jordan content 0.